# Adding UISearchBar to UINavigationController in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c

Now that searchDisplayController has been deprecated, is there a way to add a UISearchBar to the UINavigationController if I'm targeting only iOS 8?

Answer (score 0):

There  is option in ios 8.That is UISearchController.Go through this link.

https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISearchController